# iOS 10: cicontext.render() makes transparent areas black

Tags: ios, swift3, core-image

I'm using

```
ciContext.render(overlayImg, to: pixelBuffer, bounds: bufferFrame, colorSpace: nil)
```

where `overlayImg` is an image with transparent areas. Pre-iOS10 this worked as expected, but since iOS 10 the transparent areas are black.

I don't know exactly what changed, but how can I achieve the rendering with transparency again?

Comment: Dealing with this same problem - any success?

Comment: no, unfortunately not :( Would LOVE if you post the solution if you have one...

Comment: Post some sample code that I can run, I will try to help you as best as I can.

Comment: @Brandon Posted some sample code here where I'm dealing with a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373383/inputimage-of-cifilter-is-always-black

Comment: How are you creating your CIContext?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25405096/2299040 might help

Comment: Try setting the color space instead of nil

Comment: @swalkner any update on this?

Comment: please share with the answer :)

Comment: This work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576163/cicontext-render-tocvpixelbuffer-bounds-colorspace-function-does-not-work-fo